# What do I need to learn iPhone development offline?

Tags: iphone, offline

I have a week long holiday without 'net access coming up. I'm interested in learning iPhone development. What applications, tutorials, documents and so forth should I download in order to learn and develop iPhone applications completely offline? Are there any steps I need to take to prepare my iPhone to have apps loaded on to it while I still have 'net access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you *really* need is a mac and the SDK. If you're registered as a developer, download either 2.2.1 or the newer 3.0 beta. The 2.2.1 version is fine for learning on, at least until you want to start uploading apps. Make sure the documentation you need is downloaded by subscribing to it. Click Help->Documentation and on the left, you can see the documentation sets. Click subscribe for the ones you want, or all of them if you're not sure.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action

You now have everything you need to start learning. If you want to try installing programs on your iPhone, you'll need to get a developer certificate and generate your keys. This is tricky and takes time to get right. If you don't want to do this, just use the iPhone Simulator, which is included in the SDK. Before you leave, download the Hello World program from the developer.apple.com site and try running it in the SDK. If you can "Build and Go" and see the iPhone Simulator, you should be set.

If you're new to Objective-C, pick up "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (3rd Edition)" by Aaron Hillegass. The teaching style is great and he explains the basics really well. The book is aimed at desktop programming, but there is no better introduction to Objective-C.

[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0321503619/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619)

If you need something more iPhone specific, get "Beginning iPhone Development" by Dave Mark and Jeff LaMarche. They have very in depth examples. The teaching style isn't as clear and the chapters are very long and involved but it's thorough.

[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/1430216263/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430216263)

If you need another book, get "iPhone SDK Development" from Pragmatic Programmers. It's a beta book, so there will be a few mistakes, but the style is much clearer and the chapters are a much more digestible length.

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/amiphd/iphone-sdk-development

Any one of those books will take you much longer than a week to digest, but they're good starting points. There's no harm in downloading the Stanford podcasts too for when you can't read any more, but they're no good as stand-alone guides. Don't forget to download all their PDFs which have some great exercises.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

The Stanford iPhone Programming Course is a podcast, and once downloaded, does not require net access (although some of the sample programs you write do).

[CS193P - iPhone Programming](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php)

It is a pretty complete introduction, you will be able to write real programs when you are complete, and it's probably more content than you can reasonably absorb in a week. The current class content is written for the 2.x SDK, so no beta 3.0 mess to worry about.

Comment: The 2.0 and 3.0 SDKs are incredibly similar, a few extra features, extra frameworks, and bug fixes, but really, nothing to worry about for most people.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development/332057#332057

Your question is quite close to being a duplicate.

And yes, your phone must be set in a specific development mode. All this is explained in the SDK documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I would update your SDK and  iTunes/iPhone firmware.  I would also download the podcast of the tutorials.  Finally here is a great [link](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/index.php) to a bunch of PDFs you can download and use.

Comment: Be careful if you load up the latest iPhone OS 3.0 beta on your phone.  The betas expire after a while, which is a pain if it's your main phone and you're on vacation when it happens so that you can't update to a newer beta.

Comment: very good point! Please read carefully the warnings before you upgrade any of the three aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. SDK With documentation from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action

Answer (score 0):

According to me roseindia is a good offline course but it is very expensive instead you can go for online courses like edumobile.org ,This is a good site for you to start as it cover up all the essential concepts that you need to know, so that you can make your own apps for your personal iphone without any difficulty.