# How to start programming for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I come from a .Net C# background, what's the best way to learn how to program native applications  for the iPhone?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a number of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294214/want-to-start-iphone-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356025/iphone-getting-started , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109043/starting-iphone-development

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I need to learn iPhone development offline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921297/what-do-i-need-to-learn-iphone-development-offline)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [Stanford course on iPhone development](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/). It will really get you started.

Comment: Agreed.  Apple's own videos are pretty worthless.

Comment: Best way to learn iPhone development coming from a programming-familiar background hands-down.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has posted nice resources, but even if you already know the language you have to use, I just wanted to state it so that other people who probably don't know it, can see.

The language used for developing Apple sanctioned, native applications is Objective-C. Of course, you can mix in C and C++, but the SDK itself is in Objective-C, so you might want to learn that. It looks a bit scary at first to most people, usually those coming from higher level languages such as C#. The brackets and supposed 'verboseness' turns some people off. After a while though, it grows on you and you'll notice it's a very readable and self-documenting language.

I personally used the book titled [Learning Objective-C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150) which was perfect for me as someone who is already familiar with programming languages, preferably C-style languages, and wanted to learn about the main differences in that language. The other, longer and I imagine better reference of a book is the popular [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157). This book is longer and starts off assuming the reader has 0 programming experience, going over control structures, Object Oriented Programming basics, etc. I believe both books have cheaper and searchable PDF versions.

Have fun and I hope all goes well for you in this venture.

Answer (score 0):

In case you didn't know it: You can also use C# to program on the iPhone [through MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/). And in fact MonoTouch does also compile down to native ;)

Comment: The MonoTouch approach looks interesting, but I believe developing natively in a map using the SDK might be better in the long term.

Comment: I meant "developing natively in a Mac"

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Beginning iPhone 3 Development](http://iphonedevbook.com/) book to be a very good way to get started.